# Inverse of an Infinite Dimensional Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I have an infinite matrix $P$ which is stochastic, i.e., the sum of each of its rows is 1. I would like to show that $I - aP$ is invertible where $a$ is a number between 0 and 1.

Comparing this with the scalar version, i.e., the inverse of $1-ax$ is $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} a^jx^j$ whenever $|ax|<1$, we may expect the inverse to be $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a^jP^j$. Indeed,
\begin{align*}
(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a^j P^j )(I - a P) &= 
\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a^j P^j -  \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a^{j+1} P^{j+1}\\
&=a^0P^0\\
&=I
\end{align*}
Similar can be written for $(I - a P)(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a^j P^j )$. But I think I must be making some mistake because somewhere I should use the stochasticity of $P$? Also, this is an infinite-dimensional setting with which I am not very familiar.

Comment: You do not need the stochasticity of $P$, what you need is that $a||P||<1$ for the infinite series to converge.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a specific norm that should be used here generally? Or if we can show $a\|P\|<1$ for some norm (e.g. the sup norm in this case), then that would be sufficient?

Comment: You need a matrix-norm that is sub-multiplicative here so that you have $||P^k||\le ||P||^k$ for any integer $k\ge0$. The induced $\infty$-norm is great here because $||P||_\infty=1$.